# Can't insert into a temporary table

Tags: insert, db2, temp-tables

I have connected to my new DB2 database via JDBC and am trying to create and insert a temporary table:

```
String createTemporaryTable = "declare global temporary table temporary_table (RECORD smallint) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS in TEMPTABLESPACE";
statement.execute(createTemporaryTable);

String insert = "INSERT INTO temporary_table (RECORD) VALUES (1)";

statement.execute(insert);
connection.commit();
```

This results in

> "DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704"

Creating a normal table and inserting this way results in no errors. Is there something I need to configure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must refer to the temporary table as being in the schema session. Try the insert like:

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO session.temporary_table (RECORD) VALUES (1)";
```

session is implicit when declaring the table, but for clarity I usually declare it as:

```
declare global temporary table session.temporary_table (...
```